# Regex - Link formatting

Tags: regex, excel, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have the following link in excel:

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melon_Bicycles`

I would like to retrieve the link as: `http://en.wikipedia.org`

In google doc I used: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "https?:\/\/(.[^\/]+)")`, whereas A1 is the cell with the unformated link.

Any recommendation how to implement that in excel 2010?

Comment: See answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use `LEFT` with `FIND`. Something like this

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1,9))
```

[image]

Comment: @pnuts - even better.